# Формат вывода числа в Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

У меня есть такие настройки для записи информации в строку.

```
XSSFColor baseBackgroungColor = new XSSFColor(Color.decode("#db6060"));
        XSSFCellStyle titleStyleRED = (XSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();
        titleStyleRED.setFillForegroundColor(baseBackgroungColor);
        titleStyleRED.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        titleStyleRED.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
        titleStyleRED.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
        titleStyleRED.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
        titleStyleRED.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
```

в итоге у меня число 1000000 записывается как 10000000
в можно сделать так чтобы оно записывалось как 1 000 000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DataFormat format = wb.createDataFormat();
titleStyleRED.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("### ### ### ###"));
```